# How to set the default scope when I make search?

Tags: phpstorm

How can I set the default Scope when I make a search in the project with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+F</kbd> keys in my PhpStorm 2021?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248460 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

---

At the same time / info to remember:

1. If you invoke Find in Files (or Replace in Files) while the focus is in the Project View panel (or another file list) then the Selector will be set to that specific Directory.
2. At the same time, if you invoke it while the focus is in the Editor then the last used selector should remain (be it whole Project or a specific Module/Directory/Scope).

You may also check https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143972 and related tickets there.